# Compute Types From String

Tags: typescript, types

I'm working on a game with client/server communication. The client and server communicate with each other on different "Channels," which have arbitrary names and bodies. To avoid having to memorize channel names and required parameters for each type of request, I made the following interface:

```js
export interface Channel {
  name: string;
  message_format: string;
}
```

Now I can define channels as so:

```js
export const Channels = {
  player_id: {
    name: 'PID',
    message_format: '{id}'
  } as Channel,
  join_request: {
    name: 'JOIN',
    message_format: '{roomId}:{username}',
  } as Channel
};
```

I also have the following functions to help create and parse requests:

```js
export function createMessage(channel: Channel, args: { [key: string]: string }) {
  let msg = channel.message_format;

  for (let key in args) {
    msg = msg.replace(`{${key}}`, `{${args[key]}}`);
  }

  return msg;
}
```

```js
export function parseMessage(channel: Channel, msg: string) {
  const args = {} as { [key: string]: string };
  const regex = new RegExp(`{(.*?)}`, 'g');
  let formatMatch;

  const spl = msg.split(':');

  let index = 0;

  while ((formatMatch = regex.exec(channel.message_format)) !== null) {
    args[formatMatch[1]] = spl[index++].replaceAll('{', '').replaceAll('}', '');
  }

  return args;
}
```

Currently, my Join Request Listener looks like this:

```js
function onJoinRequest(msg: { roomId: string, username: string }) {
  console.log(msg);
}
```

The Listener must be invoked like this:

```js
onJoinRequest(parseMessage(Channels.join_request, "{myRoomId}:{myUsername}") as { roomId: string, username: string });
```

My problem is that I had to define the contents of the Join Request three times:

1. In Channels, where I define message format as `{roomId}:{username}`
2. In the function definition of `onJoinRequest`, where I defined `msg` as `{ roomId: string, username: string }`
3. When invoking `onJoinRequest` where I assert that the object returned by `parseMessage()` is of the type `{ roomId: string, username: string }`.

I want Typescript to be able to infer the type of `msg` from `Channels.join_request.message_format`, because I only want to define the parameters of a message body once. Because `parseMessage()` will always return an object in the format defined in `message_format`, I feel like defining the type of `msg` three times is bad programming practice.

Is there any way to have Typescript infer the type of `msg` in the listener based on the contents of `message_format`.

Comment: If you can remove the dependency of this question on socket.io so that the code can serve as a [mre] in a standalone IDE like the TypeScript Playground, you might get more traction here.  If not, hopefully someone with both TS and socket.io expertise will come along to help.  Good luck!

Comment:  I see that the socket.io *tag* has been removed, but the example code still either depends on it or is otherwise not appropriate as a standalone example.  Ideally, you'd [edit] the code so that when dropped into an IDE like [the TS Playground, (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/W4Ob4m), it immediately demonstrates the issue without unrelated problems like undefined/undeclared types and values.

Comment: @jcalz Sorry about that, it should be better now

Comment: Thank you.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m0yznW) meet your needs?  I'm not sure if the format is always key names in curly braces delimited by colons.  If it works for you I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, thank you! It works perfectly. Can you please explain how the `MessageFormatKeys` type works?

Comment: I'll do so in my answer, which I'll write up when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want the compiler to look at a string literal like `'{roomId}:{username}'` and extract `'roomId'` and `'username'` from it to use as keys.  This is possible using [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types).

First, in order to have any hope of doing this, you need to preserve the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the properties in `Channels` (or at least the `message_format` properties).  In your original definition, the type of `message_format` was inferred to be `string` by the compiler.  That's often what people want when they use string literals, but it's not desirable here.  One way to do this is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) when defining `Channels`:

```
const Channels = {
    player_id: {
        name: 'PID',
        message_format: '{id}'
    },
    join_request: {
        name: 'JOIN',
        message_format: '{roomId}:{username}',
    }
} as const;
```

This tells the compiler to treat `Channels` as being as specific and immutable as possible.  Here's the type of `Channels` now:

```
/* const Channels: {
    readonly player_id: {
        readonly name: "PID";
        readonly message_format: "{id}";
    };
    readonly join_request: {
        readonly name: "JOIN";
        readonly message_format: "{roomId}:{username}";
    };
} */
```

---

Great, now we can write a type function `MessageFormatKeys<T>` which takes a `message_format`-styled string literal type `T` and produces a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the keys contained within.  You didn't specify exactly what the rule is, so I'm going to assume that we can just grab whatever we find between pairs of curly braces.  Here's one way to write it:

```
type MessageFormatKeys<T extends string, KS extends string = never> =
    T extends `${infer F}{${infer K}}${infer R}` ?
    MessageFormatKeys<R, K | KS> : KS
```

This is a [tail-recusive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) which starts with a string `T` and an accumulated list of previously-extracted keys `KS` (which we initialize to `never`).  Given the string `T` we see if we can break it into chunks:

- everything before the first open curly brace `"{"`; call this chunk `F` (the First chunk)
- the open curly brace `"{"`
- everything before the next close curly brace `"}"`; call this chunk `K` (the Key)
- the close curly brace `"}"`
- everything after that; call this chunk `R` (the Rest of the string).

If so, we discard `F` and the curly braces, and recursively compute `MessageFormatKeys<R, K | KS>`; that is, we add the key `K` to the union in the accumulated list, and continue processing with the rest of the string.

If we *can't* break up the string `T` into those chunks, then there are no more keys and we just return the union of keys accumulated so far.

Let's make sure it behaves how we want:

```
type Test1 = MessageFormatKeys<"{id}">;
// type Test1 = "id"

type Test2 = MessageFormatKeys<"{roomId}:{username}">;
// type Test2 = "roomId" | "username"

type Test3 = MessageFormatKeys<" blah blah {key1} blah blah {key2} etc {key3} ho hum">
// type Test3 = "key1" | "key2" | "key3"

type Test4 = MessageFormatKeys<"{abc{def}ghi}">
// type Test4 = "abc{def"
```

The first two are exactly what you want.  The others are the logical consequences of the implementation of `MessageFormatKeys`; it doesn't really care about anything not encased in curly braces, and you can't nest curly braces because.

---

Once we have `MessageFormatKeys<T>` we can write `MessageType<T>` which is an object types with keys in `MessageFormatKeys<T>` whose property types are all `string`s:

```
type MessageType<T extends string> =
    { [P in MessageFormatKeys<T>]: string };

type Test5 = MessageType<"{roomId}:{username}">;
/* type Test5 = {
    roomId: string;
    username: string;
} */
```

---

Now that we have the tools to describe the types we want, we need to make `createMessage()` and `parseMessage()` use them.  This involves changing them to have [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) call signatures.  Here's one way to do it:

```
function createMessage<T extends Channel>(
  channel: T, args: MessageType<T["message_format"]>): string;

function parseMessage<T extends Channel>(
  channel: T, msg: string): MessageType<T["message_format"]>;
```

We give the `channel` input the generic type `T` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Channel`, from which the `args` input to `createMessage()` and the output of `parseMessage()` is given the type `MessageType<T["message_format"]>`, meaning that we use the `message_format` property type of `T` to determine the keys.

If you try to just change the call signatures you'll start seeing errors in the implementations; the compiler is just not clever enough to verify that the functions actually do what the call signature claims to do.  One way to get this working without changing the implementation is to make the functions single-call-signature [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads); you declare the call signature first, and you implement it immediately afterward.  For example:

```
// call signature
function createMessage<T extends Channel>(
  channel: T, args: MessageType<T["message_format"]>): string;

// implementation
function createMessage(channel: Channel, args: { [k: string]: string }) {
    let msg = channel.message_format;

    for (let key in args) {
        msg = msg.replace(`{${key}}`, `{${args[key]}}`);
    }

    return msg;
}
```

---

Let's test it out!

```
const msg = parseMessage(Channels.join_request, "{myRoomId}:{myUsername}"); // okay
msg.roomId.toUpperCase(); // okay
msg.username.toUpperCase(); // okay
msg.oops; // error!
// Property 'oops' does not exist on type 'MessageType<"{roomId}:{username}">'

createMessage(Channels.join_request, msg); // okay
createMessage(Channels.player_id, msg); // error!
// Argument of type 'MessageType<"{roomId}:{username}">' is not 
// assignable to parameter of type 'MessageType<"{id}">'.
```

Looks good.  The compiler knows that `msg` is of type `MessageType<"{roomId}:{username}">` which has string-valued `roomId` and `username` properties.  And thus it accepts it in `createMessage(Channels.join_request, msg)` and rejects it in `createMessage(Channels.player_id, msg)`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAs4hBANsgbwFgAoZc5EOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG5SLlbHG4bCAH0YAeyjU4YBs1YhOpAL6lVJBGJDM0mbHkbIAvIW4UADrjgBPaMOAATBsTI8KVWgwDkABQCSAEU8AGlNXXgh+QRFxSWkvAgclT1DkJRCXcgArMVBhKAgARwBXCJkTDNd3emRPACkAeV8AOWCUnj4BIVEJKTLPAigxMWpfeyU6AiLGaCqk9J4VEiVkOAMNLTAuElIAegAqZHXtDCwcXEYnFPy4e01cK2QLa1sHS4qea9uQe8oaaoAiPz+f5bMLkT53B4dKLdWJlf4JMYglJKUEUCHfB7ZXL5YqlN5g5AYn5VBj-BrNZHvdEQG6Q8KRLoxXpkgZDEZjCZTGZ-JRUhZbZZ7HZqMBWMwoACyEU6EAAYj1pABpCBWRgAHgAKsgIAAPSAgewGOTsILIJUAZR1+oghuNLHYRkoEAAbtAAHxGFLavUGo3IAAGABIEiAYNBkHKlAQQ6Bw1BzUolLGwxGAEpKAPIAD8KWljPlirAKrV6rTZqVyAAPuaLZ6GJa1KQxRLkJrSgBGJ352UKuEljUIxL-d1bHY7ZAtlDt5hd4z-Bz-UXi6elABM3ZlUT7vQH6oRg2Go3Gk2mUFmI7HE6nbfXTv+h45-2ryH+3PPfyX2xIN5nYAAzJuBY7sqqqDsgABGljoJB0GEAA1qqHbLFBcAwahMEEIhVhrssEBgAgCGqv+yzoGIyDoEU1Ajrs14rrezCAfO2Eds+Nb-Nha5sa+2H-l+zb0X+AAsQG9kWe4InAEEIAQ9gQDAShsOgwB8u6tGToJpQifOUkyXJMD8T+9E9lEmorlq1p+va8hsJ6hgpAQyAANreMgoDICZQggcWYFau6AC6sgOgoqRbAJrZ-gArKJpnmQe7LHlyZ4XqOuwHL+pTRcYzgfAljhMMFigVO+pIFTZgrIMKTYkDARQgAgYDAJohzXJAnkQBZvq2v6Jx6Lg7oABQILoZwMJqZpwFAbAXB5W5CGZEpak5-zQkyRb-P57oAJRBeVpC1fVjXNQgrUQO1Q0jXgDC9WcE1TTNjlOfBu3sIFZWOkoW3lDwuD4bwjBsE6w2nHgAB0q3REWYUVDEyADb9YDINhbkgCs91fTlYLUADTrY2woP5E8SADQGMZYaqSYBmapMhpN01Paq-mU1taLkIsVz4UU57-UV7M1XVDVNajZiTdM7WdTado6CD-UXTLY1mnjL0KDts0FgtHWastEOwr0G2pfzh1C48otnXNEBy3112XbgisA8rbAYykRyI3TBjZcsqyEM52EO29JohaizuaNo+RCLqTo4AA7sgaYQGwACiupmCTBADaDezZltmZmp4bCeCzKQI8gzLSJK0jDdDPAu0wFi4wDoOMBYwBgANnh0AXVcUMXoByRHxgAAxd+QUfKb9cMDaXYDlwRMHGGHeqg3qEAIJbZzg+buvSFtX0AISGMYIBFLguBO9S5Bu05U8z8NTkdv5-lOk3uBOb3eoANTv-5BMQETEAAIInzbgQYINQC4-z-oA3Abc5hgMLhUPmHxObczdisAwWArCCjUAdQWzVNC1ByCAOOeJmADSVt7R8owHZmhKn8B2qQz7VxDmIX6oNcBiDYGQgG8C+Y1zxk6EWUAxbmwGjdfQoNsQgDyIUEozAzQImoFYNMeUTyKIAKrJV5P8FmyBxzIDEPBawpA8YEzyqDMAYg1FmAlFAVAqwLY6L0QYoxJATG0NoOYyx1joB2OmANRxE5nFWGMQ3IYZhGAcF0ROaAgwoC73Ut4QYNixQ1DCYwTwyBbgREoGIRGepgDaGajeTw7UNb7jZEeTkp4eS0FUskb8J1aRtREWI84EjCHSJIWAO2jtIlOMMcE9Qp1zqtMYKDJ4NgoB2HsD0gJOooCxPiSQPR-8ppUVtIjMQMANKthKebMp8VKknncRAOpbkDAgFycgdSqxGDADYFQKCKALEmygH8SACYtk7JQHs9WcVER1NBmofBhDiGyNboI4RBZRE2zGZIzp4L5EEEUcoo5Ex1GaNqdo+BpAjgsIgGwjhA1IVm2haM8ZlhJnTKReIMQZgrB8i2qDBwnirE2N8Q4r6ei5T1HqN4AAmkAA)

Comment: Dropping a comment just to say thank you for writing this concept up. I've seen many projects in the wild that use this or a variation of this and it has helped a lot of people.